# Emit error after timeout in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to emit an error if a method's execution takes more time than a defined timeout. I have tried this (ES6):

```js
getExec() {
    return _getObs().timeout(5000, new Error("timeout reached")); //5s timeout
}

_getObs() {
    return rx.Observable.create((sub) => {
        sub.onNext(executeVerySlowMethod());
        sub.onCompleted();
    });
}
```

When I subcribe to `getExec`, it doesn't raise any error. What am I doing wrong? (`executeVerySlowMethod` is a really slow method that takes more than 5 secs)

Comment: From your question I understand that `executeVerySlowMethod` is *blocking*? If so, I don't think you can use timeout in that case. If you think about it, the outer observable is created, then the whole script blocks for some time, and only after that is the timeout *attached*. From the timeouts point of view, the outer observable emitted in *no time*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload of `.timeout()` available which takes a custom Error. This was removed in RxJs5. Your code will error because the second argument is expected to be of type `Scheduler|null`.

Also; creating an observable to wrap your function can be done easier by just using `Observable.of(executeVerySlowMethod())` which is less error-prone.

```
Observable
  .of(executeVerySlowMethod())
  .timeout(5000)
```

should do the trick UNLESS `executeVerySlowMethod()` is blocking // sync.

Comment: Can you provide a non-blocking version of executeVerySlowMethod?

Comment: Not without any implementation details about `executeVerySlowMethod`?

Comment: I'm trying to build some kind of circuit breaker, so given a timeout I want to interrupt execution when method reaches the timeout. Is that even possible in a single thread environment like Node?

Comment: It most certainly is possible. Most important is not to block the eventloop. Simplest way to be able to abort work like in your case is to use promises (no longer listen to the answer) or Observables (actively cancel work when unsubscribed to). Have a look at [hystrixjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hystrixjs)

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me a lot. HystrixJs uses `setTimeout` to solve what I need: https://bitbucket.org/igor_sechyn/hystrixjs/src/43b83fbbf93ee6385b48d6c3592423cd7c59812f/src/command/Command.js#lines-19 Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is the new way to do it: (RxJS6)

```js
import { of, TimeoutError, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

of(executeVerySlowMethod()).pipe(
   timeout(5000),
   catchError(err => {
      if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
         throw new Error('timeout reached');
      }
      return throwError(err);
   }))
```

Comment: You've forgot to re-throw original error in `catchError()` operator.